# Backbone: Two Change Events on Model Save

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

When I try to update a model in Backbone via `save` the change event on the model is fired twice.  Events are fired in this order.

1. change
2. request
3. change
4. sync

However, if I pass `(wait: true)`, only the first `change` event is fired.

Can anybody explain why this is happening, and how I can get `change` to only fire once without passing `(wait: true)`?

Two change events:

```
    editItem: function() {
        this.model.save({
            name: "Howard the Duck"
        });
    }
```

One change event:

```
    editItem: function() {
        this.model.save({
            name: "Howard the Duck"
        }, (wait: true);
    }
```

Pseudo code:

```
App.Views.Item = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on("change", this.changing, this);
        this.model.on("request", this.requesting, this);
        this.model.on("sync", this.syncing, this);
    },

    events: {
        "click a": "editItem"
    },

    editItem: function() {
        this.model.save({
            name: "Howard the Duck"
        });
    }

    changing: function() {
        console.log("changing");
    },        

    requesting: function() {
        console.log("requesting");
    },

    syncing: function() {
        console.log("syncing");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a decomposition of what happens when you save a model while changing attributes:

1. `model.set` with the data passed as argument
   triggers a *change* event when `options.wait` is falsy
2. XHR request
3. `model.set` with the data returned from the server
   triggers a *change* event when `options.wait` is truthy or the data returned by the server is not what the model knows

Your server probably returns a modified property which triggers the second *change* event. Either modify your response or restrict your event listening with

```
this.model.on("change:name", this.changing, this);
```

Compare these Fiddles

- http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/ZWFWx/
   the response is what the client sent
   you should see *change* - *request* - *sync*
- http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/QT3YJ/
   a version emulating your problem where the server adds a value not present in the model
   *change* - *request* - *change* - *sync*

Comment: Blerg! Thanks @nikoshr for leading me to the answer. Because my database was updating properly, I didn't think it was anything on my server. I was in fact returning `true` in addition to updating the database: thus, two change events.